# Update "Enabled" and "Locked" properties for a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to enable and unlock a subform when a record is inserted in the table behind the subform. The subform, "sfrmSaplingCount", is a subform of "frmData". I'm using a popup form to get the information from the user to create the record and also enabling and unlocking the subform. The subform is locked and disabled until it actually has a record for the user to interact with.

```
Private Sub cmdSaveSaplingCount_Click()

Dim strSQL As String  

strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblNETN_MicroplotEventSaplingCount   
(MicroplotEventID, TaxonID, SaplingCount, 
TaxonomicReferenceAuthority_IdentificationID, ProtectedStatusID) VALUES 
(" & Me.OpenArgs & ", " & Me.cboTaxonID & ", " & Me.SaplingCount & ", " & 
intTR & ", " & intPS & ")"

CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Forms.frmData.sfrmSaplingCount.Form.Requery
Forms.frmData.sfrmSaplingCount.Form.Enabled = True
Forms.frmData.sfrmSaplingCount.Form.Locked = False
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmNewSaplingCount"
```

"Run-time error 2465: Application-defined or object-defined error" is returned on the statements to enable or unlock the subform.

The 2 statements giving me problems are:
"Forms.frmData.sfrmSaplingCount.Form.Enabled = True" &
"Forms.frmData.sfrmSaplingCount.Form.Locked = False"

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, forms don't have Locked and Enabled properties, controls have them. Subform/Subreport container is a control and does have these properties. Recommend naming container different from the form it holds, such as ctrSapling.

```
Forms.frmData.ctrSapling.Enabled = True
Forms.frmData.ctrSapling.Locked = False
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. Forms, in the context of being a subform of another form are controls, which would have "Enabled" and "Locked" as properties. Articles I read instructed to add ".Form" after the name of the subform control to define the subform control as a "form" type control. Your answer didn't have the ".Form", after the name of the subform so I removed it from my code and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: It's because not setting property of form. And even for the Requery, it is not needed. Sometimes "Form" will be needed but not for the 3 lines in your code.